# How to use View Binding on BottomSheetDialog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding, android-bottomsheetdialog

I'm trying to make a BottomSheetDialog inside my MainActivity, but right now I'm using synthetic to bind my views. But now I'm stuck with how to attach `ViewBinding` to my `BottomSheetDialog`.

Here's what I do, using synthetic.

```kotlin
dialog = BottomSheetDialog(this, R.style.BottomDialogStyle)
dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.test_dialog, dialog.mainContainer, false)
dialog.setContentView(dialogView)
```

And here is what's confusing me with `ViewBinding`

```kotlin
dialog = BottomSheetDialog(this, R.style.BottomDialogStyle)
binding = TestDialogBinding.inflate(?)
dialog.setContentView(binding.root)
```

From my example above, I'm wondering what I should fill the parameters with, because unlike in an activity where I could just fill that parameter with `layoutInflater` or in a `RecyclerView`
Adapter where I cant fill that parameter with

`LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, and false`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You also can create a LayouInflater :

```
val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(requireContext())
```

then pass inflater to :

```
binding = TestDialogBinding.inflate(inflater)
```

Comment: I tried using ```requireContext()```, but that function is not available in my MainActivity. Is it okay if I just use ```dialog.layoutInflater``` instead?

Comment: If you are initializing ViewBinding in a Activity, you just need put this ( your MainActity) into LayoutInflater.from(this);

Answer (score 4):

For Binding follow as mentioned :

```
 bottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog(mContext, R.style.BottomSheetDialogStyle)
 mBottomSheetBinding = TestDialogBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, null, false)

 bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(mBottomSheetBinding!!.root)
 bottomSheetDialog.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `BottomSheetDialog` class define binding variable:

```kotlin
private var binding: BottomSheetDatePickerBinding
```

Then you can override `init`

```kotlin
init {
    binding = BottomSheetDatePickerBinding.inflate(
        LayoutInflater.from(context)
    )
    setContentView(binding.root)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val view = PostShareSheetDialogBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, null, false)
val dialog = BottomSheetDialog(it, R.style.AppBottomSheetDialogTheme)
```

at the end of dialog

```
dialog.setContentView(view.root)
dialog.show()
```

add this into style.xml

```
<style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppModalStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bottomsheet_rounded_background</item>
</style>
```

And rounded corner shape as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/margin_large"
        android:topRightRadius="@dimen/margin_large"/>
</shape>
```